# How do I pass Electron's globalShortcut's to renderer?

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

A webapp I'm wrapping up in Electron has keyboard shortcuts implemented, I want to make them global. Sadly there's no way for me to access the functions that are called on keyup etc so I can't just register the combinations for proper functions.

I know Discord desktop app had the same problem and they reimplemented that in custom Rust module, is there any open source solution like that?

This just doesn't work

```js
globalShortcut.register("Control+Shift+I", () => {
    //pass to renderer
});
```

In the perfect world it would just pass they keybinds pressed into the window somehow. The solution needs to be cross-platform and it can't require root privileges (in-case it's emulating user input)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.